# Data URI not displaying on Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm using the Paintbrush.js library to change the color of certain images. The images act as layers and when the user clicks a color from the color panel, the selected layer changes color.

http://example.com/builder/wheelprosnew/default.cfm

When the user clicks on a color, the script adds the approapiate classes for Paintbrush.js on to the image element and reloads the image. Paintbrush.js then turns the PNG to a Data URI through HTML5 Canvas.

On firefox, the data URI image is created. I can see it on Inspect Element, when I hover over the element. But it will just not display on the browser window. I have checked the appropiate CSS properties (display, visibility, z-index). There are no errors on the console except for the expected ones(same ones as on the Paintbrush.js example):

```
SyntaxError: Using //@ to indicate sourceMappingURL pragmas is deprecated. Use //# instead wb-loader2.cfm:5
Error: http://example.com/js/wb-loader2.cfm?id=7&wheel= is being assigned a //# sourceMappingURL, but already has one
Use of getPreventDefault() is deprecated.  Use defaultPrevented instead.
```

My question is, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution: I removed all the crossOrigin="anonymous" attributes from everywhere and now it is working in all browsers

Answer (score 0):

If you have `crossorigin="anonymous"` on your image, then you've come across a Firefox bug where it won't load data URI images with that attribute. Refer to:
[Bug 1109693 - canvas drawImage fails with data:image source and crossOrigin flag set](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1109693)

According to the bug tracker, the fix was issued in April 2015 and will land in Firefox 40 (see the `Target Milestone` field)